# How to indent a \halign?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tex-core, indentation

I have a weird problem. I want to indent a `\halign`, but it seems no matter what I try, it just does not like to be indented! Things I've tried:

```
text
\indent\halign{&#\hfil\cr
  foo& bar\cr
  baz\cr}
\bye
```

and

```
text
\hbox to\parindent{\hfil}\halign{...
```

and

```
text

\indent\halign{...
```

and

```
text
\hskip\parindent\halign{...
```

and

```
text
\hglue\parindent\halign{...
```

And variations of these. How can this command be so stubborn?

**Note** that I know a way to make it indented:

```
text
\tabskip\parindent\halign{...
```

but I don't want to use that because it will affect `\noalign`ed `\hrule`s and such.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\halign` is *vertical* mode material, so either you need to put the space into the alignment rows (using tabskip glue or by putting space into the preamble for the first column) or (if you don't mind stopping page breaking) put the whole alignment into a `\vbox` then use

```
\leavevmode\vbox{\halign.....
```

In which case it would get the normal parindent indentation, which is more or less LaTeX's tabular environment.

Comment: I got bit by the vertical mode **yet again**! *sigh* when will I learn. Thanks!

Comment: More precisely, `\halign` is a `<vertical command>` (TeXbook, p. 286), so its appearance ends horizontal mode by adding a `\par` token.